# Prove that the following expression is a multiple of 21

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How would you mathematically prove that the following expression is a multiple of 21 for any given non-negative integer $k$?

$$5\times25^k+16\times4^k$$

Comment: modular arithmetic

Comment: So you mean, 5*25^k+16*4^k mod 21 = 0?

Comment: it would have to be so to divide by it ...

Comment: you could also prove divisibility by 7 and 3 separately as they would also have to divide into it.

Comment: A technical point that you will find important in future:  If it doesn't have an  = sign, it is not an equation.

Answer (score 3):

Hint $25^k\equiv4^k \mod{21}$.

Comment: The teacher ended up helping me, she wanted a proof by induction. Hint p(k) => p(k+1)

Comment: @MasterJohn I am glad that your teacher helped you.